# Retrieving Twitter data based on Twitter ID in CodeIgniter using OAuth

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using a script to fetch data of a particular Twitter user id. The twitter user id is `1897279429`.

I want to show its name and image. I have the following script using the Twitter library.

```
        $this->load->config('twitter');
        require_once APPPATH.'libraries/TwitterAPIExchange.php';
        $settings = array(
            'oauth_access_token' => $this->config->item('access_token'),
            'oauth_access_token_secret' => $this->config->item('access_token_secret'),
            'consumer_key' => $this->config->item('consumer_key'),
            'consumer_secret' => $this->config->item('consumer_secret')
        );


        /** Perform a GET request and echo the response **/
        /** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
        $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json';
        $getfield = '?username=SaswatRoutroy';
        $requestMethod = 'GET';
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                    ->performRequest();
```

The issue is that I want the name and the URL of the profile picture to be displayed, but instead I get the following:

```
{"ids":[],"next_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0","previous_cursor":0,"previous_cursor_str":"0"}
```

Now it may be because I don't have any follower, and the URL is wrong. But I want the appropriate way and URL.

Comment: Did you do crawl Twitter really often? Like minimum sending hundreds of request a day.

Comment: The below answer appears to resolve the problem that you had, Saswat. While it is not strictly mandatory to accept answers here, it is certainly polite to do so. Would you do that now?

Comment: @halfer. The Twitter ID belongs to me, and it is not suspended.

Comment: It appears it was suspended at the time, since that's the Twitter handle that Ben tried. His stack trace error is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just you.  I just put that user ID into a Twython script I have to look them up and got this:

```
bash-3.2$ ./id-show.py 
User to show: 1897279429
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./id-show.py", line 14, in <module>
    data = twitter.show_user(user_id=target)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/twython/endpoints.py", line 426, in show_user
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/twython/api.py", line 230, in get
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/twython/api.py", line 224, in request
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/twython/api.py", line 194, in _request
twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), User has been suspended.
bash-3.2$
```

So there you have it, whoever that was has been suspended.

Comment: I tried it on my own, but I don't get the same error

Comment: It could just be that someone else registered that username since the account was suspended 2+ years ago.  Or maybe the account was unsuspended in that time.  Depends on whether you checked the user ID or the username ... nevermind, I just checked, the account was unsuspended which is why you didn't see the same error.